# Error! When sharing a post to Facebook in background

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using a API call to share a post to facebook. 
I am getting a error when i click a share button.

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x9289500 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

How can i solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

code 2500 means that FBSDK failed to retrive user information; check whether your FBAppId is correct with all settings

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate the latest Facebook SDK into your project from the following link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios